# SeleniumException: Timed out after 30000ms error

Tags: selenium, junit, rc

I am getting same error, it just open the mention URL and closes the browser with following error
com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: Timed out after 30000ms

Following is the code i am trying with Selenium RC and junit

Comment: possible duplicate of [Timeout after just opening the URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15176563/timeout-after-just-opening-the-url)

Answer (score 1):

The page is taking more than 30000ms to load.

Try to change the time.

```
selenium.waitforPagetoLoad(60000)
```

instead of

```
selenium.waitforPagetoLoad(30000)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use looping and inside loop you can check specific element on the page is loaded or not.so that counter will wait till that elements get loaded, this way you can apply dynamic Wait control in your code.

```
for (int second = 0;; second++) {
        if (second >= 160) fail("timeout");
        try { if (selenium.isTextPresent("add element on the page here")) break; } catch (Exception e) {}
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    selenium.setTimeout("0");

    selenium.waitForPageToLoad("0");
```